# Odd writing of files after first iteration of the whole ArrayList

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist

Yet another question from me. After circling through an ArrayList once and populating another correctly, my for loop goes on and populates the other list oddly. I can't really understand why. Please can somebody give me a fast response?

```
public SearchResult getNearby(ClientDescriptor clientDescriptor) {
    final int R = 6371; //Earth's radius
    List<HotelDescriptor> hotelsforit = new ArrayList<>();
    Result tempRes = new Result(clientDescriptor,hotelsforit);
    for (HotelDescriptor i : hotelData) {
        double n = i.getCoordinates().getLatitude();
        double dist1 = clientDescriptor.getCoordinates().getLatitude() - i.getCoordinates().getLatitude();
        double dist2 = clientDescriptor.getCoordinates().getLongitude() - i.getCoordinates().getLongitude();
        double latDist = toRad(dist1);
        double lonDist = toRad(dist2);
        double a = Math.sin(latDist / 2) * Math.sin(latDist / 2) +
                Math.cos(toRad(i.getCoordinates().getLatitude())) * Math.cos(toRad(clientDescriptor.getCoordinates().getLatitude())) *
                        Math.sin(lonDist / 2) * Math.sin(lonDist / 2);
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        double distance = R * c;
        double radius = clientDescriptor.getRadius();
        System.out.println("The distance between " + clientDescriptor.getName() + " and " + i.getName() + " is " + distance + " kilometers");
        System.out.println();
        if (distance < radius)
            tempRes.hotels.add(i);
    }
    return  tempRes;
}
```

Input :

> Hampton by Hilton;Bulevardul 21 Decembrie 1989 67, Cluj-Napoca 400124;46.775113;23.601878;2;350;1;400;1;650
>
> Grand Hotel Italia;Strada Trifoiului 2, Cluj-Napoca 400478;46.752879;23.605848;2;360;1;420;1;700
>
> Beyfin;Piata Avram Iancu 3, Cluj-Napoca 400098;46.771342;23.596176;4;300;8;370;0;600
>
> Hotel Opera Plaza;Strada General Traian Mosoiu 10-12, Cluj-Napoca 400132;46.768870;23.600571;4;450;8;520;2;800
>
> Grand Hotel Napoca;Strada Octavian Goga 1, Cluj-Napoca 400698;46.771694;23.576061;5;450;7;450;3;800;
>
> Hotel Confort;Calea Turzii 48, Cluj-Napoca 400193;46.763728;23.597908;6;200;7;200;1;350
>
> Hotel Paradis;Strada Ciocarliei, Cluj-Napoca 400124;46.779862;23.611739;7;200;8;250;1;400
>
> Hotel Sunny Hill;Strada Fagetului 31A, Cluj-Napoca 400497;46.716030;23.573740;4;150;6;190
>
> Golden Tulip Ana Dome;Strada Observatorului 129, Cluj-Napoca 400352;46.751989;23.576580;0;330;0;350;0;600

And the odd output after writing into a .csv :

> Hampton by Hilton,Single,2,350.0,Double,1,400.0,Suite,1,650.0,
> Beyfin,Single,4,300.0,Double,8,370.0,Suite,0,600.0,
> Hotel Opera Plaza,Single,4,450.0,Double,8,520.0,Suite,2,800.0,
> Hotel Paradis,Single,7,200.0,Double,8,250.0,Suite,1,400.0,
> Hampton by Hilton,Single,2,350.0,Double,1,400.0,Suite,1,650.0,
> Beyfin,Single,4,300.0,Double,8,370.0,Suite,0,600.0,
> Hotel Opera Plaza,Single,4,450.0,Double,8,520.0,Suite,2,800.0,
> Hotel Confort,Single,6,200.0,Double,7,200.0,Suite,1,350.0,
> Hotel Paradis,Single,7,200.0,Double,8,250.0,Suite,1,400.0,
> Grand Hotel Italia,Single,2,360.0,Double,1,420.0,Suite,1,700.0,
> Hotel Confort,Single,6,200.0,Double,7,200.0,Suite,1,350.0,
> Grand Hotel Italia,Single,2,360.0,Double,1,420.0,Suite,1,700.0,
> Beyfin,Single,4,300.0,Double,8,370.0,Suite,0,600.0,
> Hotel Opera Plaza,Single,4,450.0,Double,8,520.0,Suite,2,800.0,
> Hotel Confort,Single,6,200.0,Double,7,200.0,Suite,1,350.0,
> Golden Tulip Ana Dome,Single,0,330.0,Double,0,350.0,Suite,0,600.0,
> Hampton by Hilton,Single,2,350.0,Double,1,400.0,Suite,1,650.0,
> Grand Hotel Italia,Single,2,360.0,Double,1,420.0,Suite,1,700.0,
> Beyfin,Single,4,300.0,Double,8,370.0,Suite,0,600.0,
> Hotel Opera Plaza,Single,4,450.0,Double,8,520.0,Suite,2,800.0,
> Grand Hotel Napoca,Single,5,450.0,Double,7,450.0,Suite,3,800.0,
> Hotel Confort,Single,6,200.0,Double,7,200.0,Suite,1,350.0,
> Hotel Paradis,Single,7,200.0,Double,8,250.0,Suite,1,400.0,
> Golden Tulip Ana Dome,Single,0,330.0,Double,0,350.0,Suite,0,600.0,

This one is for a client searching hotels in a 1 km radius.
As you can see, the first 4 lines are totally correct then the addition to the list goes nuts.

The distances:

The distance between - and Hampton by Hilton is 0.3174609238931157 kilometers

The distance between - and Grand Hotel Italia is 2.578986251311183 kilometers

The distance between - and Beyfin is 0.9022687388120708 kilometers

The distance between -and Hotel Opera Plaza is 0.8944861012510631 kilometers

The distance between - and Grand Hotel Napoca is 2.316705705166163 kilometers

The distance between - and Hotel Confort is 1.4985385967615898 kilometers

The distance between - and Hotel Paradis is 0.6178315047415021 kilometers

The distance between - and Golden Tulip Ana Dome is 3.4824383011487625 kilometers

Comment: Hampton is written, Beyfin is written, Hotel Opera Plaza is written and Hotel Paradis too, then it goes totally nuts,

Comment: could you do a `System.out.println(radius);` to see the value of `clientDescriptor.getRadius()`

Comment: Problem solved. I had a for in plus. Sorry for the time wasted. :(